# Which of the three situations is correct use of symbol $\binom{n}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics

I know this is a silly and simple question, but I am confused by the symbol $\binom{n}{r}$. I am studying combinatorics. In the book, it uses $\binom{n}{r}$ in the following three situations: 
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}---(combination)$$ 
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}----(permutation)$$
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!}-----(?)$$

I think the correct way should be 
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}---(combination)$$ 
$$P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}---(permutation)$$

Comment: The common usage is the first one. I have never seen the other two.

Comment: I would say the second two are simply wrong.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Can you tell use which book and cite an example of where it uses the incorrect thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first definition is also named $ C(n,r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \begin{pmatrix}{n \\ r} \end{pmatrix}$
This is called a Combination and is the number of NON-ordered Committees of size $r$ you can make out of a set size $n$. Remember C = Combination = Committee.

The second definition is also named $P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. The bracket form is NOT used for this.
$P(n,r)$ is called a Permutation and it is the number of *ordered* Parades of length $r$ you can make out of a set of size $n$. Remember P = Permutation = Parade.

The formula $\frac{n!}{r!}$ is non standard and while it may come up in various work it doesn't have a specific name. The bracket form does NOT mean this.

Answer (score 3):

Only the first one.

There is a technical term for the other two:
Wrong.